# What await does exactly and does it have anything to do with microtask queue?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to understand what `await` does and what is its relation with microtask queue. The following code is just for clarification purpose only.

```
async function afunc() {
  console.log("a1");
  const b = bfunc();
  console.log("a2");
  b.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
  return "a value";
}

async function bfunc() {
  console.log("b1");
  await console.log("waiting");
  console.log("b2");
  return "b value";
}

const a = afunc();

a.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});

console.log("script end");
```

And the results are:

```
a1
b1
waiting
a2
script end
b2
a value
b value
```

On MDN it says

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment.

When does this 'resume' happen exactly? And does it has anything relatable to microtask queue in terms of execution order?

Also, I expect `b value` to show up before `a value` since it seems that `b.then()` will be pushed in microtask queue before `a.then()` is, and the actual output confused me a lot.

Any help would be much appreciated!

*Edit*:
If you remove `await` in bfunc, the result would be like:

```
a1
b1
waiting
b2
a2
script end
b value
a value
```

Comment: async/await is syntactic "sugar" for Promises ... so it's like `.then` ... by the way, `function afunc` being `async` is pointless since you never `await` in it

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for replying! The reason for `afunc` to be `async` is only to pair results with `bfunc`, it is for clarification purpose.

Comment: sure, I know, but you're confusing yourself by doing so

Comment: Before i going to write an answer do you know how Javascript promises work ? because it's important for understanding how the await operator works

Comment: @AngryJohn I know the basics of promises, mostly from MDN and some online tutorials, but I am new to JS, I haven't been able to utilize it in practical situation very much.

Comment: "*I expect `b value` to show up before `a value`*" - you should not expect anything. Since `afunc` fails to wait for the `b` promise in any way, you've got two completely independent promise chains, each executing at its own pace.

Comment: "*it seems that `b.then()` will be pushed in microtask queue before `a.then()` is*" - `b.then(…);` is called before `a.then(…);` is called, but they push the callback to the microtask queue only once the promise actually resolves. And `b` resolved later than `a`, due to the extra `await` step that it does.

Comment: Notice that `await console.log("waiting");` is equivalent to `console.log("waiting"); await undefined;`

Comment: @Bergi yeah, I put it there just to have a indicator in the result, what is behind await is not important.

Comment: @Bergi That clears a lot of things! Thank you so much! I didn't realize that microtask queue only accept resolved promise handler.

Answer (score 2):

When MDN says `resume execution of the async function`, it means that it will wait for the function inside to be completed, then continue running the outer function.

For example:

```js
async function outer() {
    console.log("outer function start");
    await inner();
    console.log("outer function end");
}

async function inner() {
    console.log("inner function start");
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000));
    console.log("inner function end");
}

outer();
```

Will log:

```
outer function start
inner function start
* 1 second pause *
inner function end
outer function end
```

I think the reason you are seeing the logs out of order is because you are running `b.then`, but there is also code outside of the async callback, so the code afterwards isn't necessarily run in order.

JavaScript promises work because of microtasks, so they are related.

> JavaScript promises and the Mutation Observer API both use the microtask queue to run their callbacks. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for replying! Please correct me if I am wrong about this: await will execute the expression behind it and collect the rest of the codes in current function and enqueue them in the microtask queue, and when call stack is empty, the microtask queue starts to execute following FIFO rule. Is this right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the microtasks part (I haven't really looked into them), but otherwise the order in which the code executes part seems right to my knowledge.

Comment: If my assumption is true, I don't understand why `a value` logs before `b value`. When the main script finishes, I suppose the microtask queue should be like [ the rest of code after await in bfunc, b.then, a.then ], which after execution should log `a value` at the end.

Comment: The `return "a value"` doesn't wait for `b.then` to finish - it just starts running. And b/c `bfunc` has more stuff to do, it logs `a value` before `b value`. (I think — I'm not 100% sure about all the microtasks stuff.)

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I will keep looking, thank you for your inputs!